# Multiple actions for a swipe gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an iOS 7 project and I have run into a problem. I want the user to swipe and for two actions to happen (a sound and a movement) but only one is happening.

I have setup the outlets and the received actions correctly but no luck.

Right now the movement works and the sound works separately but not together.

Any suggestions

Thanks

Action-Code

```
-(IBAction)Change3:(id)sender
{
      UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.tif"];
      [Change3 setImage:img];
}

-(IBAction)Change2:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.tif"];
    [Change2 setImage:img1];
}

-(IBAction)Change1:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image3.tif"];
    [Change1 setImage:img2];
}
```

Code to play the sound:

```
    NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Jump" ofType:@".wav"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL, &PlaySoundID);
```

Comment: please add the code corresponding code.

Comment: Code for the sound              
    NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Jump" ofType:@".wav"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL, &PlaySoundID);

Comment: Everything else is in the storyboard

Comment: How does the movement happen? What method is connected to your IBAction?

Comment: The other method is the changing of the image code               -(IBAction)Change3:(id)sender{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image3.tif"];
    [Change3 setImage:img];
    
 }

-(IBAction)Change2:(id)sender{
    UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.tif"];
    [Change2 setImage:img1];
    
}
-(IBAction)Change1:(id)sender{
    UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.tif"];
    [Change1 setImage:img2];

Comment: please edit your question with this code. it's unreadable as a comment.

Comment: i don't see your problem.. When should the sound be played?

Comment: The sound and the image change should happen at the same time on the same swipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your method to play the sound from inside your `IBAction` method.
Like this:

```
-(IBAction)Change1:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image3.tif"];
    [Change1 setImage:img2];

    NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Jump" ofType:@".wav"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL, &PlaySoundID);
}
```